find median price from table
I get the following error when executing an sql query and can’t figure out what I’m doing wrong, please help me. The purpose of the query is to calculate the median cost of orders for all tables - even
Text error:
"No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts."
columns:
rn - result function row_number
price - values price
sql text:
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN (SELECT MAX(rn) FROM even) % 2 = 0 
        THEN (
            (SELECT price FROM even WHERE rn = (SELECT MAX(rn) FROM even)::decimal // 2)
            +
            (SELECT price FROM even WHERE rn = (SELECT MAX(rn) FROM even)::decimal // 2 + 1)
        ) / 2
    ELSE 
        (SELECT price FROM even WHERE rn = (SELECT MAX(rn) FROM even)::decimal // 2 + 1) 
END AS median_price
FROM even

I tried changing all the data types.

Simply (SELECT MAX(rn) FROM even) / 2 would perform integer division and not cause an error. Integer division of a non-integer (decimal) does not make much sense here.

The SQL query you provided is likely erroring due to the use of // for integer division, which is not standard SQL syntax. Instead, you should use the / operator and handle the integer division using the FLOOR or CEIL functions.
SELECT CASE 
WHEN (SELECT MAX(rn) FROM even) % 2 = 0 
    THEN (
        (SELECT price FROM even WHERE rn = FLOOR((SELECT MAX(rn) FROM even) / 2))
        +
        (SELECT price FROM even WHERE rn = FLOOR((SELECT MAX(rn) FROM even) / 2) + 1)
    ) / 2.0
ELSE 
    (SELECT price FROM even WHERE rn = FLOOR((SELECT MAX(rn) FROM even) / 2) + 1) END AS median_price FROM even


It is because calumn you are selcting is not corrent type to perform operations like MAX. use CAST operator rather than directly using column name like
CAST(column_name AS UNSIGNED)
This will convert column value into integer.

@RahulKada almost but not quite. Postgres does not support unsigned integers, nor any other unsigned numeric types either. The proper statement would be the SQL standard cast(<column_name> as integer) or the Postgres specific <column_name>::integer. BTW Welcome to the SO community.
